# Plotly js - Why are there 2 x-axes? Overlaying issue

Tags: javascript, graph, plotly, plotly.js, linegraph

There seems to be an issue where there seems to be rendering 2 x axes? You can see there are 2 lines, and the 0's aren't aligning properly.

[overlaying issue in plotly js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRqb6.png)

```
var production_trace = {
      x: soy_year,
      y: soy_production,
      type: 'scatter',
      name: 'Soy production (tonnes)',
    }

    var harvest_trace = {
      x: soy_year,
      y: soy_harvest,
      type: 'scatter',
      name: 'Soy area harvested (ha)',
      yaxis: 'y2',
    }

    var soy1_data = [production_trace, harvest_trace]

    var am_layout = {
        title: 'Soy production and area harvested',
        height: 500,
        hovermode:'closest',

          yaxis: {title: 'yaxis title'},
          yaxis2: {
            title: 'yaxis2 title',
            titlefont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
            tickfont: {color: 'rgb(148, 103, 189)'},
            overlaying: 'y',
            side: 'right',
          }
    }
```

My best guess is there is an issue with the starting values of my data? I'm not sure.
(Data e.g.)
x: 1970
y1: 1508540
y2: 1318809
[snippet of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAvRf.png)

I followed the plotly library example exactly and there are still issues. Is it an issue with my data?

---

Comment: There isn't two X axis, just two Y axis with two separate zero-line that don't match. You can probably solve that with that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798553/plotly-two-y-axis-same-position-of-zero-line